# Move Burndown chart along with the backlogs and tasks from one work area to another

Tags: tfs, migration, backlog

We have a current iteration assigned to a team and the development is underway. But recently the developers moved to a different team.

I created a new team and assigned the iteration to the team and moved the backlogs and tasks.

The issue I am facing is the burndown chart is not getting moved to the new team/work area. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about project management

Comment: This is not a PM question it is a technical TFS configuration question

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunate you are a little bit stuck. The burndown is generated based on the history if the work under the Area and Iteration path specified. As the history of your data was done under a different location TFS is correctly assuming that you are starting a new Iteration.